# Get specific data from GRIB2 file

Tags: java, grib

Is there anyone who managed to get some data from GRIB2 files using Grib2Tools library in java?

Although sample application shows some data from GRIB file it does not show how to get any relevant data for latitude/longitude, ie. temperature, humidity, pressure, cloudbase, etc.

I am guessing this part is where data from GRIB2 file can be pulled but i don't see any way of it returning any meaningfull data:

```
 // Get grid data
        double latitude = 42.198921;
        double longitude = 16.548130;
        System.out.println("Value at (" + latitude + ", " + longitude + "): " + gribFile.interpolateValueAtLocation(gridid, latitude, longitude));
        float val = gribFile.getValueAt(0, GribFile.degToUnits(latitude), GribFile.degToUnits(longitude));
        System.out.println("Value at: " + val);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the getValueAt function of the Grib2Tools library basically does two things:

- it maps the coordinates passed as parameters to the closest point of the data grid contained in the GRIB file,
- it decodes the data at that grid point from the GRIB specific encoding such that you get the actual value.

The interpretation of the returned value has to be done by the user of the lib. There are basically two aspects:

- you have to know which data you accessed. This is known from the input GRIB file. Usually each variable is contained in a separate GRIB file, so if you process a GRIB file containing temperature data, you will get temperatures, if you process a GRIB file containing pressure data you get air pressure.
- you have to interpret the value according to the unit in that it is provided. The unit is usually provided in the meta data of the GRIB file, in this case in the Product Definition Template. Also this Template (and all others) can be accessed using the Grib2Tools lib conveniently. Temperature, for example, is usually provided in Kelvin, so you need to subtract 273,15 to obtain Celsius.

I hope that helps.